# Exception at Save using MongoDB driver

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, intellij-idea

My question is about an exception that is thrown when executing the following code:

```
    public boolean createUser(String name, String nickname, String password) {
    Hash h = new Hash();
    String hashedPass = h.hashPassword(password);
    MongoCollection users = Connection.connect().getCollection("users");
    RegisteredUser rUser = new RegisteredUser(name, hashedPass, nickname);
    users.save(rUser);
    return true;
}
```

The crash happens at the         users.save(rUser); and is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.fixAccess()V
at org.jongo.marshall.jackson.JacksonObjectIdUpdater.mustGenerateObjectId(JacksonObjectIdUpdater.java:48)
at org.jongo.Insert.preparePojo(Insert.java:72)
at org.jongo.Insert.save(Insert.java:47)
at org.jongo.MongoCollection.save(MongoCollection.java:128)
at aud.io.mongo.MongoDatabase.createUser(MongoDatabase.java:40)
at rest.Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

I'm using the following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jongo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

How is this happening?

What I tried:
- Reimporting via maven
- Changing mongoDB version (this code worked on an older project using 3.5.0)

Database is online and works.

My guess:
incompatible dependency versions

Comment: Which version of jackson you are using? It seems to me some incompatibly with jongo and jackson.  did you tried with jongo 1.3.1? https://github.com/bguerout/jongo/issues/319

Comment: This solved it thank you! No clue why on the old project which also used jongo 1.3.0 this wasn't an issue..  If you can answer in a normal post I can close this

Answer (score 1):

using  jongo 1.3.1 fixed this issue see https://github.com/bguerout/jongo/issues/319